# Migration creates unexpected ID field, though not explicitly specified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

C# Code First migration creates additional field namely `[WebsiteUser_UserID] [int]`, though not explicitly specified.

I have created few properties, such as `PostedBy` and `CensoredBy` in the child class(`LessonComment`) which references the parent class field `[WebsiteUser].[UserID]`. However when I run the command `Update-database -script` it creates a field `[WebsiteUser_UserID]` in the child class.

**WebsiteUser.cs**

```
public partial class WebsiteUser
{
    public WebsiteUser()
    {
        this.Courses = new List<Course>();
        this.LessonComments = new List<LessonComment>();
        this.UserLessons = new List<UserAssessLesson>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    [Required]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public Nullable<int> RoleID { get; set; } 

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } // New
    public virtual ICollection<LessonComment> LessonComments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserAssessLesson> UserLessons { get; set; }
}
```

**LessonComment.cs**

```
public partial class LessonComment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }  

    [ForeignKey("CourseLesson")]
    public int LessonID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostedBy")]
    public int PostedByUserID { get; set; }

    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }        

    //  CENSORSHIP DETAIL (If comment is censored)
    public Nullable<bool> IsCensored { get; set; }  // Comment will not be displayed until verified
    [ForeignKey("CensoredBy")]
    public int CensoredByUserID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> CensorDate { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string CensorReason { get; set; }  

    //  Navigation Properties
    public virtual CourseLesson CourseLesson { get; set; }
    public virtual WebsiteUser PostedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual WebsiteUser CensoredBy { get; set; }

}
```

**SQL Script**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WebsiteUser] (
[UserID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[PasswordHash] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
[RoleID] [int],
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.WebsiteUser] PRIMARY KEY ([UserID])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LessonComment] (
[CommentID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
[Comment] [nvarchar](500),
[LessonID] [int] NOT NULL,
[PostedByUserID] [int] NOT NULL,
[DatePosted] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Censored] [bit],
[CensoredByUserID] [int] NOT NULL,
[CensorDate] [datetime],
[CensorReason] [nvarchar](100),
[WebsiteUser_UserID] [int],  -- How is this created ???
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.LessonComment] PRIMARY KEY ([CommentID])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_LessonID] ON [dbo].[LessonComment]([LessonID])
CREATE INDEX [IX_PostedByUserID] ON [dbo].[LessonComment]([PostedByUserID])
CREATE INDEX [IX_CensoredByUserID] ON [dbo].[LessonComment]([CensoredByUserID])
CREATE INDEX [IX_WebsiteUser_UserID] ON [dbo].[LessonComment]([WebsiteUser_UserID])    
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LessonComment] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.LessonComment_dbo.WebsiteUser_CensoredByUserID] FOREIGN KEY ([CensoredByUserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[WebsiteUser] ([UserID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LessonComment] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.LessonComment_dbo.CourseLesson_LessonID] FOREIGN KEY ([LessonID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[CourseLesson] ([LessonID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LessonComment] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.LessonComment_dbo.WebsiteUser_PostedByUserID] FOREIGN KEY ([PostedByUserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[WebsiteUser] ([UserID]) ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LessonComment] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.LessonComment_dbo.WebsiteUser_WebsiteUser_UserID] FOREIGN KEY ([WebsiteUser_UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[WebsiteUser] ([UserID])  --No idea how this is created
```

**Expected result is that the additional field `[WebsiteUser_UserID] [int]' should not be created.**

Comment: Where is your DbContext?

Comment: Change `[ForeignKey("PostedBy")]` to `[ForeignKey("PostedByUserID")]` and put it on your navigation property, do the same with others.

Comment: The problem is that enityframework for map a ForeignKey to parent class follow up a propery to same name as parent class name in child class. change PostedByUserID to WebsiteUserId or using fluent api for map

Comment: Amin that's not the solution. Should I change both `PostedByUserID` and `CensoredByUserID` to `WebsiteUserID`; since they are referencing WebsiteUser class.. Can a class have 2 properties with exact same name?

Comment: Aldert, I tried many times; did you not have time to try? There are 3 ways to define navigation 
1 `public int PostedByUserID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PostedByUserID")]    
public virtual WebsiteUser PostedBy { get; set; }`

2 `[ForeignKey("PostedBy")]
    public int PostedByUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual WebsiteUser PostedBy { get; set; }`

Read [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/navigation-property-with-code-first-navigation-property-in-ef/) under **Ways to define Foreign key in Entity Framework**

**I discovered the issue and answered my own question**

Answer (score 0):

Solved using **`InverseProperty`** annotation in the Parent Class:

```
public partial class WebsiteUser
{
// ...
    [InverseProperty("PostedBy")] // Solved the problem
    public virtual ICollection<LessonComment> LessonComments { get; set; }
}
```

**NOTE:** As there are more than 1 foreign key in the child class (**PostedBy, CensoredBy**) so there was a need to explicitly provide the `InverseProperty` annotation in the Parent class.

Read the following [article](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx"InverseProperty-Data Annotations-attribute-in-code-first")